# Grid image in shopping cart in magento dashboard

Tags: product, magento-1, grid

please check attached snap-shot:

[image: snap-shot]

I am trying to Get image on shopping cart grid, but its showing no image, please check my code:

```
    ))->addColumn('image', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
        'type'  => 'image',
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'image',
```

I have made changes in this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Cart.php`.

Please help.

Comment: First thing dont change in the core file always use rewrite concept of magento

Comment: How, Please Guide me.. How to Get Image..

Comment: Hi have Put this code in end of the code, But image showing crack i means not showing image..                                                                                                                    
public function callback_image($value)
 {
    $width = 70;
    $height = 70;
    return "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/product'.$value."' width=".$width." height=".$height."/>";
 }

Comment: can you provide me link or something

Comment: i am working in remote , can u pl give me code so i can change from my end.

Answer (score 0):

- Module in this case named Custom_MyModule, the code you need is in these files below.

app/etc/modules/Custom_MyModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Custom_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custom_mymodule>
                    <file>custom_layout.xml</file>
                </custom_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custom_mymodule>
                <class>Custom_MyModule_Block</class>
            </custom_mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/custom_layout.xml

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_viewcart>
        <reference name="admin.customer.view.cart">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>image</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Image</header>
                    <type>text</type>
                    <renderer>custom_mymodule/adminhtml_renderer_image</renderer>
                </arguments>
                <after>sku</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_viewcart>
</layout>
```

app/code/local/Custom/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Image.php

```
<?php

class Custom_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $productId = $row->getProductId();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        if($product->getId()){
            $image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75);
            return
                '<img id="image_banner' . $product->getId() . '" src="' . $image . '" />';
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

- After all, clear the caches and check it out.